# c - running 2 threads in parallel with a shared variable

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, volatile

Just a beginner to threads, I'm just doing a task which involves these 2 threads.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int count = 0;

void waitFor(unsigned int secs)
{
    unsigned int retTime = time(0) + secs;
    while(time(0) < retTime);
}

void func1(void * args)
{
    printf("In func1 ...\n");
    long i = 0;
    while(1){
        i++;
        if(count == 1)
            break;
    }
    printf("The total number counted is: %ld \n", i);
    count = 0;
    i = 0;
}

void func2(void * args)
{
    printf("In func2 ...\n");
    waitFor(3);
    count = 1;
}


int main()
{
    pthread_t th1, th2;

    int j = 0;
    while(j++ < 4){
        printf("\nRound:\t%d\n", j);

        pthread_create(&th1, NULL, (void*)func1,NULL);
        pthread_create(&th2, NULL, (void*)func2, NULL);

        pthread_join(th1,NULL);
        pthread_join(th2,NULL);
        waitFor(3);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've read various references and to my understanding pthread_join() means that if there are 2 or more threads, then they will wait for one thread to finish its execution and then next one will start executing and so on.

But when i run this program, the moment pthread_join(th1) is executed, both threads are created and executed 'concurrently'. How is this happening?
Output:

```
Round:  1
In func2 ...
In func1 ...
The total number counted is: 897651254 

Round:  2
In func1 ...
In func2 ...
The total number counted is: 1051386065

........
```

My goal is to run these 2 threads in parallel. For now, join seems to do this; or am I going wrong somewhere?

And I've read that using volatile is not preferred for threads in C. So is there any way I could use count as a signal from thread 2 to 1?

Comment: Where did you read "if there are 2 or more threads, then they will wait for one thread to finish its execution and then next one will start executing"? Pthread_join simply wait for the threads you gave as an argument to terminate. What makes you think that your treads were created when you called pthread_join? Your threads were created and started with pthread_create.

Comment: Concurrent read/write access to shared variables (`count` here) needs to be protected. This typically is done using a mutex. See the `pthread_mutex_*()` functions on those.

Comment: @alk, if I lock count in func2, won't my whole func1 stop until func2 unlocks count? or statements up till 'count' in func1 gets executed and waits until func2 unlocks it? then this means there is no concurrency right?

Comment: If any answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer. This will indicate to the community that  you found a solution and will give some reputation to you and the answerer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote:

> my understanding pthread_join() means that if there are 2 or more threads, then they will wait for one thread to finish its execution and then next one will start executing and so on

That is incorrect. Join simply means that the process waits until the thread has terminated.

Quote:

> the moment pthread_join(th1) is executed, both threads are created and executed 'concurrently'.

That is incorrect. The threads are created and start when calling `pthread_create` Note: By **start** I mean that they are ready to execute. However, it is the OS that decides when they actually get to execute so it may take some time before they execute.

To share `count` between two threads you can use a mutex.

```
int count = 0;
pthread_mutex_t lock;
```

When accessing `count` you must first lock the mutex, read/write the variable and unlock the mutex.

Example:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
count = 1;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

Example:

```
long i = 0;
while(1)
{
    ... code not using count ....

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    if(count == 1) 
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        break;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    ... code not using count ....
}
```

And in `main` you'll need to initialize the mutex like:

```
pthread_mutex_init(&lock,NULL);
```

Comment: I know threads starts executing the moment we do 'pthread_create'. Does this mean parallel exection? And when I try without 'pthread_join', my thread 2 doesn't even start. Why?

Comment: @infoseeker - yes, in parallel. But the meaning of parallel may differ from system to system. Simple single core CPUs just use time sharing while multi-core CPUs can run threads truly in parallel.

Comment: @infoseeker Quote: `without 'pthread_join', my thread 2 doesn't even start. Why?` I can't know without having details about your system. A guess could be that `main` completed before the `threads` actually executed. In any case, join is required as you need to wait for threads to terminate

Comment: @infoseeker: Just leave `main()` by calling `pthread_exit()`. It's just nothing more or less then another thread. If `main()` ends by simply `return`ing, then the whole process will end along with all its threads. The latter looks to you as if the threads didn't even start.

Comment: You might like to mention that simply define a mutex variable (as shown by your code snippet) isn't enough to use it. It needs to get initialised beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for the info!